# Which board game does Nash play in the movie "A Beautiful Mind"?

Tags: analysis, a-beautiful-mind

In the movie *A Beautiful Mind*, around the 9th minute, what is the name of the game they play?

Why is Nash so surprised at losing this game?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Would you consider, putting a link in the text pointing back to the movie. Additionally, a clip, if available, would be great. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

Comment: A side note about `Go`: It's said that it's one of the more complicated game (much more than chess), and that Artificial Intelligences wouldn't be able to beat best players until some years (happened in fact last year with Alphago of Google Deepmind). That game, which is complicated reflects a lot the intelligence behind the man in the movie.

Comment: @Larme I don't recall Go being mentioned in the book.  As I recall, the games they played in real life were mainly a variant of chess played with 3 boards where the players can only see their own pieces (a referee is required) and the game Hex which was invented by two different people independently, one of them being John Nash.  Go is a great game but this movie varies from the real story of John Nash greatly.  This is minor in comparison to a lot of the unpleasant aspects of Nash that were left out completely.

Comment: @JimmyJames: I'm just pointing out that since Go is a "complex" game, it can help viewer to understand that the guy is really smart. I'm not talking about reality, but more on the message that the game chosen by the film maker can be justified.

Comment: @Larme OK but in one part of the movie Nash freaks out when he doesn't win even though he went first.  This doesn't make much sense since his work in game theory around this kind of property was related to Hex.  It also misses the bigger point that the kind of games Nash was interested in weren't necessarily complicated.  Some were so simple as to be boring to a kindergartner.

Comment: I vtc'd as off topic because this question doesn't add any appreciation to the film or it's production.

Comment: Given the consensus that the answer you accepted is wrong, could you switch your acceptance to the right answer?

Comment: @DForck42: Apart from the popularity of this question, it seems fair to me that one would appreciate the scene more if one had a better idea what game they were playing.

Comment: @DForck42 No appreciation?? Can I remark that everybody else on this site has completely ignored this movie until now. We should applaud user48040.

Comment: please visit our help page for on-topic questions, it explicitly says "Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title."  http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: if you'd like to discuss this in further detail, you can find me in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room

Comment: @PJTraill If you feel this knowledge adds to the appreciation of the movie and its story and themes, feel free to add that motivation into the question.

Comment: @MrLister "everybody else on this site has completely ignored this movie until now" Based on what? The absence of questions? So not having questions after having watched a movie is "ignoring" it?

Comment: Quite frankly, this latest edit should be rolled back, since it completely changed the question and even worse ***invalidated the answers***. The question as posed and answered is trivia; if the user had an underlying question he should pose it as a different one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is a Go board. However, the game played is **Hex**

[image]

[image]

[image]
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(board_game)):

> Hex is a strategy board game for two players played on a hexagonal
>   grid, theoretically of any size and several possible shapes, but
>   traditionally as an 11×11 rhombus. Players alternate placing markers
>   or stones (Go stones make ideal playing pieces) on unoccupied spaces
>   in an attempt to link their opposite sides of the board in an unbroken
>   chain. One player must win; there are no draws. The game has deep
>   strategy, sharp tactics and a profound mathematical underpinning
>   related to the Brouwer fixed point theorem. It was invented in the
>   1940s independently by two mathematicians. The game was first marketed
>   as a board game in Denmark under the name Con-tac-tix, and Parker
>   Brothers marketed a version of it in 1952 called Hex; they are no
>   longer in production. Hex can also be played with paper and pencil on
>   hexagonally ruled graph paper.

[Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-this-chess-like-game-called):

> Recall that in the movie, Mr. Nash looked amazed at losing. "But...I
>   had the first move. And I played perfectly!" This is because the game
>   Hex is "solved." With perfect play on a symmetric board, the first
>   player will ALWAYS win. Nash himself proved this in 1952, so this
>   scene was another reference to Nash's mathematical work.
>
> However, proving the existence of a solution does not necessarily mean
>   you can execute it perfectly every time (the proof in this case was
>   not even a constructive one, Nash doesn't have an algorithm for
>   winning, just proof that such a solution exist!).
>
> **Go boards are frequently used for Hex games, and many people have
>   confused the two while watching the movie. Go is also both more
>   popular and more complicated game than Hex, lending to the confusion.**

[the conversation](http://theconversation.com/john-nash-a-beautiful-mind-and-its-exquisite-mathematics-42333):

> Nash is also credited with inventing a game, eventually marketed by
>   Parker Brothers as a board game called Hex. This game, played on a
>   parallelogram-shaped field of hexagonal cells, was discovered
>   independently in Denmark around the same time. In Princeton it was
>   called Nash, after its creator, or John, a double entendre involving
>   the fact that it was played on the tiles in the mathematics
>   department’s men’s room floor. There are two players, each of whom has
>   tokens of a single color (red and blue, say). The object is to form an
>   unbroken path from one side of the board to the other before one’s
>   opponent does the same in the opposite direction.
>
> There are online versions of the game. The first player always has a
>   winning strategy; that is, the player who makes the first move can
>   always win, provided he executes the proper sequence of moves.

Clip - A Beautiful Mind - "The Challenge" - A Game of Go:[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmlSSSN7C78)

Comment: Sorry, according to the description you provide Hex is played "on a hexagonal grid". Go board is not "a hexagonal grid", not even close. What gives?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't Go? The clip you link to starts with someone saying "I've played enough Go for one day". Perhaps Nash's annoyance is shown in the movie as a precursor to his creating Hex, precisely because he considered Go "flawed" since he lost despite "playing perfectly".

Comment: The picture you give of the game in progress looks like a typical Go position. It looks nothing like a Hex position. There seems to be no evidence for your claim other than a statement on Quora (itself unevidenced).

It is also true that Hex is a first player win, but the strategy is unknown for a board that big so Nash cannot have known he played perfectly (though the same would be true of Go).

Comment: **This answer is wrong**.  You can tell whether Go or Hex is being played by looking at the position of the stones; the final positions in the two games look *nothing* alike.  The game in that first picture is unequivocally Go.  They even said so in the movie...

Comment: I have to agree with the other comments. While them playing Hex would be a beautiful bit of historical reference, it just doesn't hold up to studying how they are playing when watching the scene in question. No matter how I look at it, it does seem like they really are playing Go.

Comment: FWIW Nash did actually invent a board game. It's best known as So Long Sucker, although I prefer the title he originally gave it: Fuck You, Buddy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_Long_Sucker

Comment: @MattThrower he [also invented Hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(board_game)#History), although it had been invented by someone else before him, Nash reinvented it independently.

Comment: [Amateur Go shodan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_ranks_and_ratings) here. The first screenshot is Go, not Hex. No discussion about it.

Comment: also recall that he later is shown to develop a different game board in the film - that may be the connection to Hex OP is referencing. But agree - clearly the first instance is Go

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh: One could of course play Hex on a Go board, by considering all vertices to be diagonally connected in the same direction. That would be reasonable if you only had a Go board available, though you would have to concentrate that bit extra. But I agree that it looks like Go not Hex.

Answer (score 69):

Actually, according to [the script](https://www.scribd.com/doc/78729322/A-Beautiful-Mind-Script), that's [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)), not Hex:

> All right, who's next?
>
> **No, I've played enough "Go" for one day, thank you.**
>
> Come on. I- I hate this game. Cowards, all of you! None of you rise to meet my
> challenge? Come on, Bender. Whoever wins,Sol does his laundry all
> semester.

You can hear the conversation and that they clearly mention Go in [the clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmlSSSN7C78) linked to in [Mary's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/70157/43226).

Since they claim it's Go, right there in the movie, I don't see how it could be anything else.

Comment: The move makes sense (white captures a large black group) - what doesn't make sense is that Nash and the bystanders wouldn't have seen it coming until it actually happened.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft ah, as I said, I don't know Go :) Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It's possible that a combination of them playing quickly and simultaneously talking about something (mostly) unrelated was a sufficient distraction.